# Julia Differential Equations suppress warning of detected instabilities

Tags: julia, differential-equations, suppress-warnings, differentialequations.jl

I have a program that simulates the paths of particles using the Differential Equations package of Julia. The simulation allows for particles to hit devices - to prevent the continued simulation of such particles, I use the `unstable_check` of the solver (specifically of the `EulerHeun` solver). However, this leads to warnings like the following:

```
┌ Warning: Instability detected. Aborting
└ @ SciMLBase <path>\.julia\packages\SciMLBase\0s9uL\src\integrator_interface.jl:351
```

As I simulate thousands of particles, this can be quite annoying (and slow).

Can I suppress this warning? And if not, is there another (better) way to abort the simulation of some particles?

I don't think a code sample makes sense / is necessary here; let me know though if you think otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://diffeq.sciml.ai/stable/basics/common_solver_opts/#Miscellaneous

> verbose: Toggles whether warnings are thrown when the solver exits early. Defaults to true.

Thus to turn off the warnings, you simply do `solve(prob,alg;verbose=false)`.

> The simulation allows for particles to hit devices - to prevent the continued simulation of such particles, I use the unstable_check of the solver

Using a `DiscreteCallback` or `ContinuousCallback` with `affect!(integrator) = terminate!(integrator)` is a much better way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

There is [`Suppressor.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaIO/Suppressor.jl), although I don't know whether this reduces the overhead you get from the warnings being created, so a DiffEq-specific setting might be the better way to go here (I don't know much about DiffEq though, sorry!)

Here's an example from the readme:

```
julia> using Suppressor

julia> @suppress begin
           println("This string doesn't get printed!")
           @warn("This warning is ignored.")
       end
```

for just suppressing warnings you want `@suppress_err`